# Cannot access file in nodejs

Tags: node.js

When running the below snippet of code to see if a file exists:

```
var fs = require('fs');

fs.access("C:\\cypressRahul\\InLoop\\cypress\\ExcelReader\\TestData.xlsx", fs.constants.F_OK, err => {
            console.log(err ? "Doesn't exist" : "Exists");
        });
```

I get the following error:
TypeError: Cannot read property 'F_OK' of undefined

Can anyone explain why I am unable to sue filesystem methods in nodejs?

Thanks.

Full file:

```
import {Log} from "../Log/Log";
import {Workbook} from 'exceljs';
import { isNullOrUndefined } from "util";


export class ExcelReader
{
    constructor ()
    {    

    }   
    wb: Workbook = new Workbook();

    public getData(cellName: string, sheetName:string, testCaseID:string) {        
        var fs = require('fs');
        cy.log(isNullOrUndefined(fs).toString());
        fs.access("C:\\cypressRahul\\InLoop\\cypress\\ExcelReader\\TestData.xlsx", fs.F_OK, err => {
            console.log(err ? "Doesn't exist" : "Exists");
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: version = v13.6.0

Comment: when i change it to just fs.F_OK i get: TypeError: fs.access is not a function

Comment: So, something is apparently seriously wrong with loading your `fs` module.  Are you 100% sure that there is no other definition of the `fs` variable in this file?  Can you show us the whole file or provide a link to the whole file?  Something else is probably going on besides what you show us here.  Another idea.  Are you using webPack (or some similar bundler) and trying to run this in a browser?  There is no `fs` module in the browser.

Comment: I am using browserify and cypress for test automation

Comment: There is no `fs` module when you run bundled code in a browser.  That explains it.  That's because a browser doesn't have any capabilities to directly access your file system the way the `fs` module does (for security reasons).